Statistical Ensembles by fixing Response functions ($C_V, \alpha$) - Maximum Entropy
Typically, most of equilibrium statistical mechanics is built on the principle Maximum Entropy subject to some constraints. These constraints fix the mean value (first cumulant) of a certain conserved quantity.
For example, in canonical ensemble, we fix the internal energy of the system to be equal to the average ensemble energy ($U = \left< E \right>$), leading the maximum entropy distribution given by,
$$
p_i = \frac{1}{Z(\beta)}e^{-\beta E_i}
$$
To be more explicit, the constraints that goes into deriving this distribution can be given as,
$$
\sum_i p_i = 1 \qquad \qquad \sum_i p_i E_i = U
$$
where the second constraint essentially fixes the mean of the random variable (Here energy being the random variable).
My question is, if I fix the second cumulant of a conserved quantity (which is E here) - energy fluctuations $(\Delta E)^2$, what is the relevance of such ensemble in physics? Why hasn't anybody approached this problem so far?
For example, if we choose additional constraints on energy fluctuations (in addition to the ones already mentioned),
$$
\sum_i \left( E_i - \left< E \right> \right)^2p_i = A
$$
and consider entropy maximization. In this case, wouldn't the probability distribution change significantly. In principle, it would have a Gaussian form (considering all three constraints)
$$
p_i \propto e^{(E_i-U)^2/(2A^2)}
$$
Addendum on the physical premise:
The fluctuations in energy are related to specific heat of the system $C_V$ at constant volume and therefore, imposing this constraint would amount fixing the $C_V$ of the system, which is not very unphysical.

I mean, why shouldn't you be allowed to use that constraint?

This is a good question, and you certainly can fix any probability distribution you like as your initial state.  That does not guarantee that the distribution that you pick is a bona fide steady-state distribution that will give correct predictions after letting the system evolve forward in time for a while.  This steady-state idea is usually what we're after in statistical mechanics, and it's why we use the Gibbs distribution in particular.
There's a difference between fixing the expectation value of $E$ and fixing the expectation value of $C_V$: $E$ is a conserved quantity.  This means that when the system fluctuates around its expectation value, it's not that energy is disappearing or appearing, but that it's passing between the system and its environment.  The way to empirically change $U$ is to change its thermodynamic conjugate variable in the environment, which for energy is temperature—this shows up as the Lagrange multiplier $\beta$ when you work out the maximum-entropy distribution.  This story also works for volume/pressure or particle number/chemical potential, because volume and particle number are conserved when they are transferred between the system and the environment, and they can be adjusted by changing pressure and chemical potential.
There's no reason that $C_V$ should be conserved in any way as an arbitrary initial state is time-evolved forwards, and likewise there's no way to tune it by changing something in the environment.  If you were to prepare an ensemble with the probability distribution that you've given, it would quickly relax to the Gibbs ensemble for the same $U$, for the same reason that any other initial configuration does: in classical statistical mechanics, we assume that our microscopic Hamiltonian is chaotic and ergodic.  This means that the  probability density will be mixed and spread out such that on any hypersurface of constant energy $E$, the conditional distribution $p(i|E)$ is constant.  For your initial ensemble this mixing alone will give the Gibbs distribution, but even for a more general initial state, it gets there by exchanging energy with the environment.
Edit: Related is the concept of a "generalized Gibbs ensemble," which is just a Gibbs ensemble on energy but also on whatever other conserved quantities whose expectation values you want to fix.  It's especially important when considering systems with very large numbers of conserved quantities, like quantum integrable systems, including ones with conformal symmetry.

Thank you for the answer. I included the reference $C_V$ only to make a certain direction to the question. But in principle, what I am asking is if I fix the second cumulant of a conserved quantity (which is E here), wouldn't it lead to a different ensemble? Why does nobody attempt to do it? Is it physically meaningless?

Any probability distribution defines a legitimate ensemble.  Most of them are just not steady-state ensembles.  Yours will quickly "thermalize," relaxing to the Gibbs ensemble, which is a steady-state ensemble.

Can you please elaborate on steady-state ensembles and ensembles which don't achieve steady state?

It's not that other ensembles "don't achieve" steady state.  Assuming ergodicity, every ensemble eventually relaxes to a steady-state ensemble.  It's just that the one that you pick as your initial condition might not itself be steady-state.
One kind of funny example: if you time-evolve a closed system that starts in an ensemble with support over more than just one value of energy, the steady-state ensemble that you get is a superposition (just classical probability, not quantum :P ) of  the microcanonical ensembles for each energy represented in the initial ensemble.
