Why should the Boltmann distribution maximize entropy with average energy constrained?
In statistical mechanics, when working with the canonical ensemble (e.g. a system able to exchange energy with a large thermostat at temperature $T$, the system together with the thermostat being isolated), we find that the probability of a given micro-state is proportional to $\exp(-\frac{E}{kT})$ where $E$ is the energy of this micro-state: that's the Boltzmann's distribution.
We can show that this distribution is the one which maximizes the Shannon entropy (as defined in information theory) under a constraint on the average energy $U = \sum{p_n E_n}$ of the system (this can be shown using Lagrange multiplier - I do not have a problem with that derivation).
In some source, I have read that we could have derived Boltzmann distribution using this maximum entropy principle, hence my question:
why should we expect the distribution to be the one which maximizes Shannon entropy under constraint on the average energy?
I mean, these results are fundamentally based on the equiprobability of all microstates corresponding to a macrostate (which leads to a maximum Shannon entropy equal to $S = \ln(\Omega)$ (with $k = 1$)), for the whole system including the thermostat.
It does not follow obviously from this that the canonical ensemble should maximize Shannon entropy under the average energy constraint for the subsytem in contact with the thermostat.

Do you mean equiprobability of the microstates from both system and bath? Because, obviously, there is no equiprobability of microstates within the system (in canonical ensemble), each microstate with energy $E$ has a probability $e^{-\beta E}$.

Sorry, what exactly is your question? You can quite straightforwardly show that the canonical ensemble is the unique probability distribution maximizing the Shannon entropy under constraint of fixed average energy. The derivation is usually covered in textbooks.

@user35952 Yes, that's why I said for the whole system including the thermostat. This is the principle on which statistical mechanics seems to be founded. I don't see how it should follow from this that for the system (without thermostat), the entropy with constraint on $U$ should be maximized (although I agree with this result, once we have identified Boltzmann distribution).

@TobiasFünke As I mentioned in the question, I don't have a problem with the fact that Bolzmann distribution maximize entropy under this constraint on $U$. What I don't understand is why this is presented as a fact that we should have expected, or even as a principle from which we could have derived the distribution.

I don't know who says that this is expected. And to be honest, I don't see how this question can be on-topic here, as it seems opinion based. As I said above: That it is indeed the (unique) distribution maximizing the entropy functional under the given constraint is a more or less easy thing to derive. There is the so-called "Maximum Entropy Principle", from which you can get equilibrium thermodynamics...

@TobiasFünke I don't think this question is opinion based. This question raises a valid concern about the choice of constraints used in Jayne's Maximum Entropy formalism to derive ensembles of Statistical Physics. A related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/825136/35952. The question will probably benefit from a bit of editing and rephrasing to make it more lucid.

You are misunderstanding the logical flow of these statements / arguments.
I particularly like Callen's textbook, because he lays classical thermodynamics on a postulatory basis before he talks about statistical thermodynamics. The downside is that it is a pretty difficult read.
The logical argument goes as follows: Making some assumptions and half of the 2nd law of thermodynamics, you can derive the entirety of classical thermodynamics. In particular, as long as you assume that thermal equilibrium arises from the maximisation of entropy at constant energy, you can derive classical thermodynamics. You can also prove that this is equivalent to minimising energy at constant entropy. All the other similar arguments on minimising thermodynamic potentials and maximising Massieu functions (N.B., these are not the same thing as Mathieu functions) follow as a consequence.
This means that by the time you reach statistical thermodynamics and now want to discuss what lies beneath classical thermodynamics, you already know that an appropriate entropy function must maximise entropy at constant (average) energy.
That is, you are somewhat getting a choice of which entropy function (Shannon = Gibbs $S\propto\sum_ip_i\ln p_i$, or Boltzmann $S_B\propto\ln\Omega$, or what other you might think of), and from there you derive the appropriate distribution function. I don't think people assume the appropriate distribution function and then derive the entropy function, because this is in general impossible, since we already have multiple entropy functions leading to the same distribution.
But it is certainly the case that, although we ``derive" the Boltzmann distribution $e^{-E/k_BT}$ from the initially assumed to be microcanonical Boltzmann entropy $S_B\propto\ln\Omega$, the actual next step is to realise that the microcanonical ensemble assumptions are way too strict and unphysical, and instead that the canonical ensemble makes far more physical sense, and thus turn around and assume the Boltzmann distribution is correct, and then derive everything else from there. Picking an entropy function that leads to the Boltzmann distribution is thus the smart way to go about it, and so we are led to the Gibbs-Shannon entropy functions.
(I don't know what language you are coming from, but we do not call the thing you call thermostat as so. It is the heat bath, or thermal reservoir, in English. Thermostat is the thing that tells the heater or fridge to switch on or off, in order to keep a system within a certain temperature range. That is thus a different thing.)

(You're right regarding thermostat, it is used for heat bath in french but doesn't seem to be appropriate in english)

Thanks. I'll be careful with that when I discuss thermodynamics with my French friends next time.

Also in Italy, we sometimes use thermostat as synonim for heat bath!

Grazie, signore

Under usual thermodynamic assumptions entropy is an extensive function, i.e., the entropy of the "system + thermostat" is the sum of the entropies of the two components:
$$
S(A+B)=S(A) + S(B)
$$
As the two parts are independent (the role of the thermostat is only to break the conservation of energy), the maximum of entropy is reached when the entropies of both parts are at their maximum.

According to me, the choice of considering the average of energy to be fixed is essentially because energy is a conserved quantity in Hamiltonian systems.
However, since for a system immersed in heat bath (thermostat according to your question), it is continuously exchanging energy with the  bath, one can anticipate that instead of the instantaneous energy, the average of energy is conserved.
As to the reason why this corresponds to canonical ensemble is probably linked to the relationship between average energy  (or internal energy) and temperature. Canonical ensemble is a system where the Temperature of the system is fixed with respect to the bath.
Now the most important question, as to the equivalence of internal energy (of thermodynamics) and average energy (of statistical mechanics) is merely from the fact that the statistical quantities from the ensemble such as,

average information - entropy $(S)$
average energy - internal energy $(U)$
temperature (defined through relationship between $U$ and $S$)

follow the equations and laws of thermodynamics, suggesting we can recover thermodynamics from statistical quantities of the theory of ensembles.
Therefore, the canonical ensemble defined basically by constraining that the temperature ($T$) of the system and bath be equal is equivalent to asking that the average energy of the system be equal to the internal energy of the system, $\left< E\right> = U$.

May I please know the reason as to why this answer was downvoted? The reason would really also help me understand the problem better.
